# Is it possible, to work with ASP.NET 2.0 or ASP.NET 3.5 under Apache 2.x?

Tags: asp.net, apache

I know, that there is a solution in the following blog:

http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2005/09/11/424852.aspx

Has anybody tried to get it work under production circumstances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url you link to mentions an old module that is no longer maintained, and doesn't work with Apache 2.2 (according to the comments to that post). Comments further down the page suggest that the [updated module](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-aspdotnet/) works with Apache 2.2 (some even got it to wotk with 3rd party components like MagicAjax, but details are sketchy. Also note the [bug list](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?atid=871785&group_id=175077&func=browse), and the fact that it hasn't been updated since mid-2007. Also note that all posts were pertaining to WAMP - I didn't see any from a LAMP environment.

I would recommend Mono for .Net 2.0 - for 3.5 you are limited to IIS for the moment. One good way to get this right is detailed @ [DoTheWeb](http://www.dotheweb.net/lama/).

Comment: Thank you. This is not the answer, I hoped for, but maybe the only real solution.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I couldn't give you the answer you wanted.